# Verify I proved that $P(A) = P(A\mid B)P(B) + P(A\mid\bar B)P(\bar B)$ correctly?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

> Proof.
>  Let $A$ and $B$ be events in a sample space $(S,P)$.
>    Suppose $0 \le P(B) \lt 1$.
>   $P(A) = P(A\mid B)P(B) + P(A\mid\bar B) P(\bar B).$
>   $P(A) = P(A \cap B) + P(A \cap \bar B)$ by definition of
>    conditional probability.
>   Note that $A \cap B + A \cap \bar B = (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap \bar B) = A$.
>   So $P(A \cap B) + P(A \cap \bar B) = P((A \cap B) \cup \mid A \cap \bar B)) = P(A).$
>   Hence we have $P(A) = P(A)$ and $P(A) = P(A|B)P(B) + P(A\mid\bar B)P(\bar B)$.

I just want to verify that the end of my proof is correct. Is it safe to assume that adding these two sets together is just the union, and I can then transfer that simplification directly over to the probability function?

EDIT (current revised proof):

> Proof.
>  Let $A$ and $B$ be events in a sample space $(S,P)$.
>   Suppose $0 \le P(B) \lt 1$.
>  $P(A) = P(A\mid\bar B)P(B) + P(A\mid\bar
>  B)P(B)$.
>  $P(A) = P(A \cap B) + P(A \cap \bar B)$ by definition of
>    conditional probability.
>  $P(A) = P((A \cap B) \cup (A \cap \bar B))$ by Inclusion-Exclusion, since $(A \cap B) \cap (A \cap \bar B) = \emptyset$, and $P(\emptyset) = 0$.
>   $P(A) = P(A)$
>   Hence $P(A) = P(A\mid B)P(B) + P(A\mid\bar B)P(\bar B)$.

Comment: The probability of the union is the sum of the probabilities because you have two sets with an empty intersection, in other words, the events cannot occur simultaneously. In this case, the probabilities simply add up.

Comment: $P(X\cup Y) = P(X)+P(Y)$ if $X\cap Y = \emptyset$. Let $X = A\cap B$ and $Y=A\cap\overline B$.

Comment: The meaning of '+' is a bit unclear. If you mean 'union', then you should apply what @peterwhy wrote.

Comment: I know that $A = (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap \bar B)$, but I am having a hard time transferring the + sign (as given in the problem) over to the union step. By that, I mean I'm wondering if the line that says Note that $A \cap B + A \cap \bar B = (A
 \cap B) \cup (A \cap \bar B) = A$ is correct.

Comment: What is your proof that you proved it?

Comment: I've updated the proof at the bottom of my question. How is it now?

Comment: What is that $ P(A\mid\bar B)P(B) + P(A\mid\bar B) P(B)$ in your question?